# Where clause with a list of field combinations

Tags: entity-framework

I have a list of field combinations that I want to search for. The list can realistically contain up to 100 items, the table I'm querying has a little over 1 million records at this time.

An example:

```sql
create table mytable
(
    foo int not null
    ,bar int not null
    ,baz int not null
)

insert into
    mytable
values
    (1, 1, 11)
    ,(1, 2, 12)
    ,(1, 3, 13)
    ,(2, 1, 21)
    ,(2, 2, 22)
    ,(2, 3, 23)
    ,(3, 1, 31)
    ,(3, 2, 32)
    ,(3, 3, 33)
```

One possible way to retrieve data:

```sql
select
    foo
    ,bar
    ,baz
from
    mytable
where
    (foo = 1 and bar = 3)
    or (foo = 2 and bar = 1)
    or (foo = 3 and bar = 2)
```

Another possible way:

```sql
declare @filtercombos table
(
    foo int not null
    ,bar int not null
)

insert into
    @filtercombos
values
    (1, 3)
    ,(2, 1)
    ,(3, 2)

select
    mytable.foo
    ,mytable.bar
    ,mytable.baz
from
    @filtercombos fc
    left join mytable on mytable.foo = fc.foo and mytable.bar = fc.bar
```

Both will return this data:

```
foo         bar         baz
----------- ----------- -----------
1           3           13
2           1           21
3           2           32
```

Now, if this was a list of single values, I could do `.Where(item => myList.Contains(item.foo))`. How can I do a query like above? The only thing I can think of is to execute SQL on the DbContext, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQKit's PredicateBuilder is what you need!

```
var query = from u in context.Users select u;
var pred = Predicate.False<User>();

foreach(var filter in combofilers)
    pred = pred.Or(u => u.Username == filter.Foo && u.Language == filter.Bar);

return query.Where(pred.Expand()).FirstOrDefault();
// or return query.AsExpandable().Where(pred).FirstOrDefault();
```

[Dynamic where clause (OR) in Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621450/dynamic-where-clause-or-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: This works, the Profiler shows that the query is expanded to `where
    (foo = 1 and bar = 3)
    or (foo = 2 and bar = 1)
    or (foo = 3 and bar = 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the list of combinations in another list you could do something like this.

```
var query = from m in Context.mytables
    select m;

foreach (var foobar in foobars)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.foo == foobar.foo && x.bar == foobar.bar);
}

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Chaining `Where` is an `and` operation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't look closely.  You can use the Predicate Builder solution from this question for the Or.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782339/how-to-dynamically-add-or-operator-to-where-clause-in-linq

Comment: Here's a better example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101540/linq-or-equivalent-of-where

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively something similar to the answers on this question might help.

[Entity Framework - Join to a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053468/entity-framework-join-to-a-list)

Comment: The first solution in that question is a stored procedure (similar to executing SQL on the DbContext), the second solution, like explained, pulls all records in memory, which I can't do with over a million records.